# Place an icon on line at first instance of a value?

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I have a gnuplot script as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot -persist

set terminal x11
line = "./test.csv"
plot line using 1 with lines linecolor 1 linewidth 3 title "Line"
```

And my `test.csv` file:

```
0.92
0.74
0.65
0.59
0.48
0.46
0.24
0.11
0.09
0.05
0.03
0.01
```

This produces a plot like so:

[image]

I want to see the point where the line has gone below `0.1`. Is there a way to mark this position either by some icon on the line or perhaps a vertical dotted line. Something like below:

[image]

For this, where `x=9`, it is the first time `y<0.1`, so it's been marked to illustrate this example.

Is there something in gnuplot that can do this? I know with line styles I can represent my line as symbols like a star or +; I'd love to have one of those at a specific point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A one round version with `pointsize variable`:

```
$line <<EOD
0.92
0.74
0.65
0.59
0.48
0.46
0.24
0.11
0.09
0.05
0.03
0.01
EOD

hit=0; plot $line using 0:1:(hit=hit+($1<0.1), hit==1?3:0) with lp ps var pt 7 lw 3 title "Line"
```

[image]

To get the bar, one can use a second `errorbar` plot.

```
hit=0; plot $line using 1 w l lw 3 title "Line",\
           "" using 0:(hit=hit+($1<0.1), $1/(hit==1)):(0):(1) w e  lc 1 pt 7 ps 3 title ""
```

[image]